# What kind of view technology used in spring boot by default

Tags: spring, spring-boot

What kind of view technology used in spring boot by default when I add the 'Spring Boot Web Starter'.
If I want to use the JSP, I need to include the 'tomcat-embed-jasper' or 'Spring Boot Thymeleaf Starter' for thymeleaf templates. So I would like to know the default view technology of 'Spring Boot Web Starter'

Answer (score 1):

By default there is no view You need to configure and add their dependencies.If You are using Spring Boot older versions then You can refer above answer but if You are using Spring Boot 2 then add on more dependency for thymeleaf-

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It means, old version of spring boot provides the JSP as default view. In spring boot 2 there is no default view, am I correct ?

Comment: why the spring boot 2 doesn't provide any view ? because the main goal of spring boot starter is to eliminate the difficulties from hunting the jars manually.

Answer (score 0):

`JSP` is supported by Spring out-of-the-box.

It can be configured like this

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }
}
```

or in properties file

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

**For Thymeleaf**

Spring Boot will provide auto-configuration for `Thymeleaf` with below dependency in pom.xml

Please make a note of version used. Also you might need to provide view properties like above

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```